# Change the processing extent of raster in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, extents

I have two rasters. One shows slope:

[image]

and the other shows Euclidean distance:

[image]

As you can see, the Euclidean layer is smaller than the slope one.

How do I change the extent of the small layer to the extent of the big layer?

I know than in ArcGIS Desktop I could do it in the properties of the layer and then choose processing extent and same as layer X, but I can't find how to do it in ArcGIS Pro.

My end goal is to have the small distance raster  have the extent of the big raster.

Comment: Does your Euclidean layer comprises all of the slope area or is it just a part of it?

Comment: Set extent to one of slope and compute distance again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Analysis -> Environments -> Processing Extent Tab -> Extent ->` Choose the from `Same As Layer ->` Select the slope layer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

on your Euclidean Distance there should be Environment tab, and Processing Extent. This does not change the entire map analysis environment, only your current geoprocessing environment. I would recommend this one because you may have different environments for different tools. [image: environment]